# Facing problems with socket programming for video streaming

Tags: python, sockets, serial-port, tcp

I have two transceivers which support serial communication (UART). I am using socket programming on python for generating UDP data grams. Is there any way to port these datagrams to the serial port on the transmitter and then back from serial port to UDP datagram on the receiver. I am new to this so some examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you can transmit enough data over serial for video streaming?

Comment: Yes. I've achieved enough compression. Video quality is not a problem. I need to port them for serial communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the point-to-point protocol (PPP).  That's what it was designed to do. 
 If you're running on Linux or some other UNIX-like operating system, you'll use `pppd` on both ends of the serial connection.

Most of the articles on setting this kind of thing up date back to the dial-up internet days.  Here's an example: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/

Essentially, PPP creates interfaces with IP addresses on both ends of your serial connection.  Send packets to the remote interface's IP address, and it tunnels them over the serial link.

Comment: This is probably the closest thing you'll get to having a network driver for a serial port.

Comment: Are there any examples for this implementation? As I said, I'm new to this.

Comment: This is not something you'd do in Python.  You'd run the daemon on your host operating system.

Comment: (Not that you *couldn't* do it in Python...  it just seems orthogonal to the problem you're trying to solve.)

Comment: Can you direct me to some site where udp over ppp has been implemented?

Comment: Check out the link from my answer, if you haven't already.  Here's a more targeted example from a subsection of that larger document that's specific to an RS-232 "null modem" serial link: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html